# How to print only the first and last 5?

Tags: python, pandas, one-hot-encoding

I would like to print the first and last 5 of my one hot encoding data. The code is below. When it prints the first and last 30 are printed.

```
Code:

from random import randint
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import pandas as pd
import datetime 
import itertools as it
import numpy as np
import csv

df = pd.read_csv('C:Users\GrahamFam\Desktop\Data Archive\Daily3mid(Archive).txt')
df.columns = ['Date','b1','b2','b3']
df = df.set_index('Date')

reversed_df = df.iloc[::-1]

n=5
#print(reversed_df.drop(df.index[n:-n]))

df = pd.read_csv('C:Users\GrahamFam\Desktop\Data Archive\Daily3eve(Archive).txt')
df.columns = ['Date','b1','b2','b3']
df = df.set_index('Date')

reversed_df = df.iloc[::-1]

n=5
print(reversed_df.drop(df.index[n:-n]),("\n"))

BallOne = pd.get_dummies(reversed_df.b1)
BallTwo = pd.get_dummies(reversed_df.b2)
BallThree = pd.get_dummies(reversed_df.b3)
print(BallOne)
print(BallTwo)
print(BallThree)
```

Comment: Yes, sorry I'll fix it.

Comment: `print(df.head(5))` and `print(df.tail(5))` ?

Comment: Looks like `print(pd.concat([df.head(5), df.tail(5)]))` would get the output you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're fine displaying the tail before the head, then can use `np.r_` slicing from negative to positive:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(list(range(30)))

df.iloc[np.r_[-3:3]]
#     0
#27  27
#28  28
#29  29
#0    0
#1    1
#2    2
```

Otherwise slice explicitly:

```
n = 3
l = len(df)
df.iloc[np.r_[0:n, l-n:l]]
#     0
#0    0
#1    1
#2    2
#27  27
#28  28
#29  29
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `head` and `tail` function. You can read about them [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.head.html#pandas.DataFrame.head)

```
>>> DataFrame.head(n) 
>>> DataFrame.tail(n)
```

where n is the no. of elements you want